# Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER); Only working in 1 of my 2 programs when the code is the same. Why?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have 1 basic program and 1 app, My basic program with this works ( DB_URL, USER, PASS, JDBC_DRIVER  all correct and functional) and I am able to get information from my MySQL DB.  The code consist of this:

```
try {
        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        // STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT distinct tags FROM items";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while (rs.next()) {

            // Retrieve by column name
            String itemRoles = rs.getString("tags");

            //Add it to the ArrayList.
            itemRolesList.add(itemRoles);

            // Display values
            System.out.print("TAGS: " + itemRoles + "\n");
        }

        // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        // Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }// nothing we can do
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }// end finally try
    }// end try
```

But when I try to apply this same code to my app (inside a Fragment in my OnCreateView()) I get this:

```
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

and it is at this line of code:

```
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
```

I added the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar" and it is in my Reference Library in both my program and app.  Does anyone know why inside my app it gives me this error?

Comment: The exception is very clear. JVM is not able to find the jar file. There is some problem with your Java Build Path.

Comment: It does sound like a dependency or classpath error.

Comment: *"Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER); Only working in 1 of my 2 programs when the code is the same."*  Is the run-time class-path the same?

Comment: In addition to what @RaunakAgarwal has said, you don't even need this line of code if you have an up-to-date MySQL JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that you have jar file inside lib folder is not the empty jar file.sometime during wrong confuguration it shows a empty jar file.
please go to project properties-->buildpath-->libraries
Check out the jar file you have added is not blank.

Comment: This was it, putting inside my libs folder :D.  What I was doing before was "build path > configure build paths > libraries > added it there"; but that didn't do the trick.  Thank you for all the answer Antriksh and everyone else's support.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have driver jar in your classpath.